# React TypeScript: No warnings or errors are thrown for possibly undefined value in array state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an array state in React with TypeScript that contains object items. The array state is initialized to an emtpy array. However, TypeScript in VSCode doesn't throw any warnings or error when I try to reference an element in the array.

```
type Data = {
  field: string;
}[];

const [data, setData] = useState<Data>([]);

const clonedData: Data = [...data]; // Clone the data state
const firstData = clonedData[0];

const firstDataField = firstData.field; // Allowed to index, TS does not throw any warnings or errors that `firstData` may be undefined
```

Does anyone what is the issue? Is there a field in `tsconfig.json` that allows setting of this particular TS warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Typescript will always assume your index is within bounds, and as such `firstData` will definitely have the type `{field: string}`.

What you are looking for is `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess`

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess

Here is a [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDeAoKUBmBLCAGwBMAuKAZ2ACc8A7AcwG4MBfAbQF0WMBjAezpUoxBEnLxEKKFwx9Bw3oUERikuBLHT2AOj2jE3KAHpjUAMLK60YAAtoBpFQQR5Q4LjzUq66UpVqYuwADNxyAu6e3sDqAGIEJNL40eo6%20ETETFBAA) that will show you the error as you want it.

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)